# Azure devops pipeline condition of plugin

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

link for the plugin : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=touchify.vsts-changed-files

```
  isPullRequest: ${{eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')}}

- job: "check"
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
  displayName: Check Files Change
  steps:  
   - task: ChangedFiles@1
     name: CheckChanges
     inputs:
       rules: |
         [Y]
         X/**


       variable: 'HasChanged'
       isOutput: true


- job: "X"
  dependsOn: check
  condition: or(eq(dependencies.check.outputs['CheckChanges.Y'], 'true'), 
  or(succeeded(), ne(variables.isPullRequest, 'true')))
```

Hello I want to make the JOB run only if a change has been made to a particular folder or the run is not from Build Validation.
Need help exactly the conditions

Comment: I checked your question as well as the answer and found that it is indeed an effective method. Please follow his steps and methods to try it first. If you have any questions and need help, we are happy to answer them.

Answer (score 0):

You can define "policies" on branches to trigger specific pipeline definition(s) when file path(s) are involved.
Here you can find the Azure DevOps [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) (please have a look at the "path filters" [part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#path-filters))